# Deserializing to object with overloaded setter with fasterxml.jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I want to deserialize json string into object which have overloaded setter for a field. I don't want to explicitly annotate one of the setter with @JsonIgnore.
Why can't jackson library use appropriate setter according to the type of value it fetches in json string?
Following is Code:

```
public class A {

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

public Set<Integer> getSet() {
    return set;
}

public void setSet(Set<Integer> set) {
    this.set = set;
}

public void setSet(String str)
{
    this.set = null;
}
}
=========================
String input = "{\"set\":[1,4,6]}";

A b = mapper.readValue(input, A.class);

System.out.println(b.getSet());
```

I got following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"{"set":[1,4,6]}"; line: 1, column: 8] (through reference chain: com.rs.multiplesetter.A["set"])
```

Comment: why on earth would `public void setSet(String str){}` set the `set` to `null`? Just call the method `clear` or something

Comment: This is just contrived small example for the issue I am facing. I don't think I need to elaborate the real issue. The question is: Why jackson library can't use appropriate setter while de-serialization, according to data type it encounters.

Comment: It still doesn't really make sense to me, why can't you just change the name of the second `setSet` method? It would make a smaller mess and be more readable. Even when this is a simplified example

Comment: Why on earth would you have an overloaded setter that accepts a `Set<Integer>` and a `String`? What's the _real world_ situation for that?

Answer (score 6):

Jackson not accept `multiple setter`. You need to specify the one `setter` by `@JsonSetter`. If you want to accept multiple type then you can handle this using `JsonNode`. Here is example:

```
public class A implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

public Set<Integer> getSet() {
    return set;
}

public void setSet(Set<Integer> set) {
    this.set = set;
}

public void setSet(String str)
{
    this.set = null;
}

@JsonSetter
public void setSet(JsonNode jsonNode){
     //handle here as per your requirement
    if(jsonNode.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.STRING)){
        this.set = null;
    }else if(jsonNode.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.ARRAY)){
        try{
            ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<Set<Integer>>() {});
            this.set = reader.readValue(jsonNode);
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
    }
}
}
```

**If you dont want to handle here then you can use custom deserialization class.